# raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'doc' in line csv_file =request.FILES['doc']

Tags: django

I really spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem.

Here is my views.py

```
def data_upload(request):
    template="Try.html"


    prompt ={}
    if request.method == "Get":
        return render (request, template, prompt)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file =request.FILES['doc']
        print(csv_file.name)
        print(csv_file.size)

    if not csv_file.name.endwith('.csv'):
        message.error(request, 'this is not a csv file')


    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
```

the error is in the line csv_file =request.FILES['doc']

Comment: Can you try with : `csv_file = request.FILES.get('doc')`

Comment: yeah I tried and it works for that line but now I can no more read data, I have this error: data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I need more context to understand. What are you trying to achieve exactly in this view ? How is it called and with what files in  `request.FILES` ? It seems to be empty, maybe try to print it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! finally, it works, this link helps me: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code and it works, here the updated function in views.py

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile']

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

            data_set = myfile.read().decode('UTF-8')
            io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
            next(io_string)

            for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
                _, created = Data.objects.update_or_create(
                    date=column[0],
                    sum_click=column[1],
                    activity_type=column[2],
                    week_from=column[3],
                    final_result=column[4],
                    highest_education=column[5],
                    num_of_prev_attempts=column[6],
                    studied_credits=column[7],
                    age_band=column[8],
                    imd_band=column[9]
                )

            print(column[0][0])
            return render(request, 'Try.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
                })
    return render(request,'Try.html',{})
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    date = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sum_click = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    week_from = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    final_result = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    highest_education = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    num_of_prev_attempts = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    studied_credits = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    age_band = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    imd_band = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

Comment: Be careful, you can still have a KeyError if the file `myfile` is not present in the request. Maybe you should add a check in your first condition : `if request.method == 'POST' and 'myfile' in request.FILES and request.FILES['myfile']:`